# breakpoint is never hit using gwt

Tags: debugging, gwt

I run the gwt module in Netbeans.then I right click the module and chose custom: gwt run. I add ?gwt.codesvr=192.168.2.113:9997 to the address and it's running. but the breakpoint is not hit.
i'm sure it's not a jvm problem because someone in the office showed me how to do it. but somehow when i do it, it goes wrong.
can anyone give a detailed instruction on this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by a few things.

First of all, make sure you actually are running debug-mode. As far as I know, if you run it without debug mode it doesn't stop at any breakpoints.

If you do have debug-mode on, are you absolutely sure it runs that piece of code where you placed the break-point.

Comment: i'm not sure whether debug-mode means the ide's server's debug mode or gwt debug, so i use both debug mode. anyway, i'll try again. thanks for help